# Why does Shift-right says it is bound to right?

Tags: key-bindings

I tried to check what function shift-right is bound to which extends the region right by a character by default. But C-h k says:

```
<right> (translated from <S-right>) runs the command right-char (found
in global-map), which is an interactive compiled Lisp function in
‘bindings.el’.
```

If S-right does something else than simple right then why does it say it is bound to right?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/54591047/324105

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taken from this emacs wiki [page](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/TheMysteriousCaseOfShiftedFunctionKeys):

> Emacs is set up so that the keys, particularly all the control-, meta-, alt- keybindings keep working if you inadvertantly leave the shift-lock key on. So it assumes that you were looking for the unshifted one if this is the only keybinding defined on that key. Hence it sees the shifted function key, checks to see if the shifted function key has been bound to a function and if it doesn’t find a keybinding, checks to see if there is anything bound to the unshifted key. If it finds a binding, it gives you that one instead of the one you asked for.

Comment: So how to find out what function S-right runs which does something else than simple right?

Comment: If there is something bound to it, it will show it. In your case there isn't so it gets translated to right. Execute `(global-set-key [(shift f1)] 'info)` and check again.

Comment: But you surely realise that S-right does more, it extends the selection even in default emacs 26.2 with -q. So it's not just for me. So the question is what function in emacs performs the shift detection part  in this case?

Comment: The intereactive code `^` in the `interactive` statement of a function is what tells Emacs to do something different if the `shift` key is depressed; e.g., `(interactive "^p")` used by `right-char` and `left-char`.  See the interactive codes section of the Emacs manual for more information:  https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Interactive-Codes.html  If we were to remove the `^` from the interactive statement in `left-char` and/or `right-char`, then the `shift` (if depressed) would have no effect.

Answer (score 5):

If an input event is not bound and contains the <kbd>Shift</kbd> modifier or is an uppercase character, Emacs converts it to the corresponding unshifted or lowercase event. This is discreetly documented in the [Emacs Lisp manual under `read-key-sequence`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Key-Sequence-Input.html#index-this_002dcommand_002dkeys_002dshift_002dtranslated-1739). Unlike what the docstring of `read-key-sequence` says, this isn't limited to the first event in a sequence: if `KEY1` is bound to a keymap (so it's a prefix key) but `S-KEY1` is not bound, pressing `S-KEY1 KEY2` results in an event for `KEY1 KEY2`. However, if `S-KEY1` is a prefix key, `S-KEY1 KEY2` remains unchanged even if `S-KEY1 KEY2` is not bound, regardless of what `KEY1 KEY2` might be bound to.

Commands can find out whether such a translation happened by checking the variable [`this-command-keys-shift-translated`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Key-Sequence-Input.html#index-this_002dcommand_002dkeys_002dshift_002dtranslated-1739). Few commands do. The only ones I can think of are the [cursor motion commands that select text when <kbd>Shift</kbd> is pressed](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Shift-Selection.html#Shift-Selection), like `right-char`. This mechanism is handled by [`handle-shift-selection`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/The-Mark.html#index-handle_002dshift_002dselection-3512) which is triggered for every command that has `^` in its [interactive specification](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Interactive-Codes.html#index-reading-interactive-arguments-1616).